# "Continue WITH love" vs "continue TO love"

Tags: prepositions

What is the difference between "continue to love" to "continue with love"? 
For example: This couple should continue with/to love.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

continue + infinitive = persist in doing the action expressed by the verb

continue with {something} = proceed in the characteristic manner or state

> We continued to see each other.
>
> We continued to visit that town year after year.
>
> We continued with caution.
>
> We continued with great hesitation.
>
> We continued with reckless abandon.

So, "to continue to love" means to not stop loving and "to continue with love" means to proceed in a loving manner.